# Emacs/AUCTeX/LaTeXmk: Default compilation command only on first run?

Tags: emacs, auctex, latexmk

When I hit C-c C-c to compile a document, my system is set up such that LaTeXmk is default typesetting option, and I just hit Enter to run it.

The next time I do C-c C-c (without any changes in the document), however, BibTeX is the default, not LaTeXmk. If I choose LaTeXmk, it runs, and says "LaTeXmk: nothing to do", which is fine. I'd just like to avoid writing LaTeXmk in the second run, if possible.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: How do you define the 'second run'?

Comment: Well, actually I just mean pressing C-c C-c again. I guess what I'd like is to be able to define what happens the second time the command is issued.

Comment: But what would you like to happen when you change something between the two compilations that needs a rerun of latexmk?

Comment: Let's say I compile my document, then i go away for a cup of coffee, and when I return, I forgot if I am looking at the most recent version. So I compile again. I guess I'd like to just make C-c C-C invoke latexmk every time. I'm unsure how to do it. Is it possible to remove the other entries in TeX-command-list somehow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer**: AUCTeX doesn't play very well with `latexmk`, by default.

---

**Long answer**: AUCTeX has its own system to decide what command to run next, when building a document.  This is based on reading the output of compilation program, but it expects only one command has been actually run.  Instead, `latexmk` runs multiple commands in a row, making AUCTeX confused.  That's why the short answer.

One solution could be to write a parser specific to `latexmk`, but this isn't super-easy.

However, note that AUCTeX is capable of automatically running all commands needed to build a document.  Just issue <kbd>C-c C-a</kbd> and you're done (the output document will also be shown automatically).  See also the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#One-Command-for-LaTeX_002c-helpers_002c-viewers_002c-and-printing).  In order for this to work, `"LaTeX"` should be the default command to be run, not the custom entry you added for `latexmk`.  The existence of this feature of AUCTeX is the reason why no one ever had the need to write the parser to make `latexmk` play nicer with AUCTeX

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation.  Then, I wonder what the proper AUCTeX way is to switch default commands depending on the directory or project?  With latexmk, you can place a configuration file in the current directory to change the behavior of latexmk .

Comment: What you mean by command? The engine (like tex, xetex, luatex)? If so, you can set TeX-engine, see https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Processor-Options

Comment: A parser for latexmk is available: https://github.com/tom-tan/auctex-latexmk. Not perfect, but good enough. For me the advantage of latexmk over `TeX-command-run-all` is that it is easy to add extra rules, and that my emacs workflow matches my terminal workflow. Also,  `C-c C-a` has confusing bindings, relying on prefix arguments unlike `C-c C-c`, `C-c C-b`, `C-c C-z`, `C-c C-r`... Ergonomically, I believe that a better choice would be to include a "Latex (all)" option in the command list... and it's exactly what `Latexmk` does.

Answer (score 0):

I [rubber](https://launchpad.net/rubber) might suite your needs here. If you are on debian `apt-get install rubber` would suffice.

then in your `.emacs`

```
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(progn
 (add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list
          '("%(RubberPDF)"
        (lambda ()
          (if
              (not TeX-PDF-mode)
              ""
 (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
        '("Rubber" "rubber %(RubberPDF) %t --shell-escape --synctex" TeX-run-shell nil t) t)))
         "--pdf --shell-escape --synctex"))))


(defun rubber ()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (let ((this-buffer (buffer-name)))   
(TeX-run-shell nil (concat "rubber " " --pdf --synctex --shell-escape "  this-buffer) t)))
(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "<f8>") 'rubber)
```